# Selenium help on switching to iframe then click on link

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am currently trying to click on each link which lead give me more info on the restaurants.
https://www.halton.ca/For-Residents/Food-Safety/Dinewise/Search-Directory-of-Food-Premises-Dinewise.

The first restaurant is 151 Social and I am trying to click on it but doesn't seem to be working for me. I already compiled a pd.Series consisting of the xpath links to each restaurant

//*[@id="lblContent"]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/a

That is just for the first restaurant

```
for element in range(len(df['Temp xPath links'])):    
    frame = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID,"iframe-form")))
    ref = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(By.xpath(df['Temp xPath links'][element])))
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", ref)
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", ref)
```

I'm struggling to enter to the next page. Any help will be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Induce `WebdriverWait`() and wait for `element_to_be_clickable`() and `XPATH`

```
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//a[text()='151 Social']"))).click()
```

**Full Code:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.halton.ca/For-Residents/Food-Safety/Dinewise/Search-Directory-of-Food-Premises-Dinewise")
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID,"iframe-form")))
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"btnOK"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"btnGetEstablishments"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//a[text()='151 Social']"))).click()
```

Comment: Great answer, you can also add another step at the end to step back to the previous page of all restaurants and then will need to add some logic to cycle to the next page once you have hit the last result on a page

Comment: To go back to the first window driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0]). Also add some time.sleep() or you'll get request errors.